# Pandas DataFrame: Compute values based on column min/max

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an NxN DataFrame with values I need to scale to a range of values that signify importance, where 0 is irrelevant and 3 is very important.

The formula I'm using to scale of course depends on the min and max values in each column, which are different for each column: Col A's range could be 1-12 while Col B's range could be 1M to 45M.

Here's the formula I'm using.

`min_importance + ((max_importance - min_importance) / (max_spec_value - min_spec_value)) * (spec_value - min_spec_value)`

How do I create a new DataFrame or dictionary with scaled values for each column, while retaining the index, which is needed later for identification?

I tried creating a function with the above formula, and using apply() to call the function for each row, but I can't pass column min/max to the function, so that doesn't work.

DataFrame sample ("Body: retail price" and "Body: sensor resolution" are columns):

```
                       Body: retail price  Body: sensor resolution  
Body name                                                            
Nikon D500                        2000.00                 20668416   
Nikon D7000                       1200.00                 16084992   
Sony Alpha 7R II                  3199.00                 42177408   
Canon EOS 5D Mark III             3499.00                 22118400   
Canon 7D Mark II                  1799.00                 19961856   
iPhone 6 (front)                   699.00                  1000000   
iPhone 6 (rear)                    699.00                  7990272   
Fujifilm X-T1                     1299.95                 15980544   
Fujifilm X-T2                     1599.00                 24000000
```

Comment: Can you use `pd.cut` to assign bins to each column?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: @ayhan I added the sample to the original question.

Comment: @JonClements That seems possible, but how would I do that procedurally since each column will have a different range of possible values that need to map to 0-3?

Comment: But this is not NxN? Is this the dataframe where you have the values for max/min importances and spec values? How would you apply that formula to this dataframe manually?

Comment: @ayhan It was just a part of the dataframe because the real one is too wide to fit. Right now, it's 9 rows x 13 columns, but will grow as more variables and rows are are added. Yes, it is the dataframe where the min/max values need to be derived. For example, for the "Body: sensor resolution" attribute, each value would be scaled based that columns min/max. Min = 1000000, which would scale to 0, and Max = 42177408 which would scale to 3. All values between would be scaled according to the formula in my question. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is 'min_importance' and 'max_importance' fixed or do they have different values for different columns?

Comment: @ayhan No, they are not fixed. Most columns will be [0, 3], but some are binary [0, 1].

Comment: So where do you have that information? In a list, dictionary, another dataframe?

Comment: @ayhan I haven't decided how to code that information yet. I was thinking a metadata table that gives the range for each variable. Do you have a suggestion for how it should be expressed? A dictionary where the keys are the column names and values are tuples of the range?

Comment: I've edited to show you how you can do it with another dataframe (it would make more sense to use a dataframe I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min-max normalization can be done with:

```
(df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
Out: 
                       Body: retail price  Body: sensor resolution
Body name                                                         
Nikon D500                       0.464643                 0.477651
Nikon D7000                      0.178929                 0.366341
Sony Alpha 7R II                 0.892857                 1.000000
Canon EOS 5D Mark III            1.000000                 0.512864
Canon 7D Mark II                 0.392857                 0.460492
iPhone 6 (front)                 0.000000                 0.000000
iPhone 6 (rear)                  0.000000                 0.169760
Fujifilm X-T1                    0.214625                 0.363805
Fujifilm X-T2                    0.321429                 0.558559
```

You don't need apply. `df.min()` will return a series and when doing `df - df.min()` pandas will subtract corresponding column's minimum value from each value. This is called broadcasting which makes the task easier.

If you have different importance levels for each column, best thing to do would be to store it in a dataframe:

```
importances = pd.DataFrame({'max_imp': [1, 3], 'min_imp': [0, 0]}, index= df.columns)
importances
Out: 
                         max_imp  min_imp
Body: retail price             1        0
Body: sensor resolution        3        0
```

Now with the same principle, you can adjust your formula:

```
importances['min_imp'] + ((importances['max_imp'] - importances['min_imp']) / (df.max() - df.min())) * (df - df.min())
Out: 
                       Body: retail price  Body: sensor resolution
Body name                                                         
Nikon D500                       0.464643                 1.432952
Nikon D7000                      0.178929                 1.099024
Sony Alpha 7R II                 0.892857                 3.000000
Canon EOS 5D Mark III            1.000000                 1.538591
Canon 7D Mark II                 0.392857                 1.381475
iPhone 6 (front)                 0.000000                 0.000000
iPhone 6 (rear)                  0.000000                 0.509280
Fujifilm X-T1                    0.214625                 1.091415
Fujifilm X-T2                    0.321429                 1.675676
```

Note that the index of `importances` and the columns of the actual dataframe should match. In this example, the first column's range is converted to [0-1] and the second column's range to [0-3].

Comment: Great I will try this and report back!

Comment: That worked great, thank you! I'm going to look up broadcasting to better how the df works.

Comment: How does it know to match the indexes to the column names?

Comment: `importances['max_imp'] - importances['min_imp']` returns a series with indices retail price and sensor resolution (range of each). `(df.max() - df.min())` also returns a series again with the same indices. The difference is how we do the operation. In the first one we subtracted one column from another - so result is returned for each row. But in the second one we subtracted minimums of columns from their maximums. Now the result is for each column.

Comment: But both results are pandas series so they have identical indices. Pandas did the operation on matching indices. It didn't know that one was from columns and one was from rows. It might be easier to play with smaller parts of the equation (executing `(df.max() - df.min())` first, then `importances['max_imp'] - importances['min_imp']` to see how it works for example.

Comment: That is very revealing about how dataframes work, thank you for the detailed explanation. I played around with the smaller parts and now understand what is happening. I come from an SQL world, which trips me up a lot; SQL works on a per-column basis and won't return max for all columns using the column names as indexes with a single command. Very cool that Pandas does that.